# Find Value's Position in Recordset With MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure if this is possible without looping through it in php, but I thought I would ask. If I have am returning a list of names with something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT address FROM customer_list WHERE state = 'CA'
```

and it returns a list like

```
45 E Elm
555 N 17th
1920 E Broadway
11 Bergren Ct
```

Is there a way for me to know that "555 N 17th" is the second item in the recordset?

Answer (score 0):

you could set a mysql variable and increment it in the query, like;

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT DISTINCT address, @rank:=@rank+1 AS position FROM customer_list WHERE state = 'CA'
```

more information on doing this can be found [here](http://www.leftjoin.net/2011/05/mysql-getting-row-position-in-result-set/). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. That is a useful way to get the row location, but it no longer selects distinct. Is there a way around that issue?